# Capturing a nil object and rendering a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I seem to be unable to capture a nil response from my api call, when there are no results I get this error

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

So if this happens I would like to show a message like 'No book found', so i have tried these

```
 <% if @results.empty? %>
 <% if @results.nil? %>
 <% if @results.nil %>
```

but none of them capture the error

Controller

```
def results
results = book_search(params[:search])
@results = results
@book = Book.new
@book.author = results.first["artistName"]
@book.bookname = results.first["trackName"]
@book.image = results.first["artworkUrl100"].gsub("100x100-75.jpg", "200x200-75.jpg")
@book.description = results.first["description"]
end
```

View

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="span8 offset2">
   <% if @results.nil? %>
    <h1 class="resultTitle">sorry we can't find anything for that book.</h1>
     <%= link_to "Back To Search", root_path, :class => 'backButton' %>
   <% end %>


  <%= @results.first["trackName"] %> <br>
  <img src =<%= @results.first["artworkUrl100"] %>> <br>
  <%= @results.first["artistName"] %> <br>
  <%= truncate(remove_tags(@results.first["description"]), :length => 250) %> <br>

  <%= form_for @book do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :category_id, "Category" %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Please select a Category') %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :author %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :bookname %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :image %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :description %>

   <%= f.submit 'Save book' %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Any ideas on what it could be

Thanks

Comment: from where? controller? what would you like to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter version will return true if `@results` is nil. You have some other error elsewhere.

If the error still shows up, then you access results even when `@results.nil?` returns true. More specifically take a look at the places where you call the square bracket operator `[]` as the error is caused by one of them.

EDIT: after discussion in chat we have discovered the problem. First in the conroller book_search returns an empty array and then, when invoking `results.first["artistName"]` this causes the error, because results.first is nil. So to fix that we added the following to the controller:

```
  def results
    results = book_search(params[:search])
    @results = results 
    unless @results.empty?
      @book = Book.new 
      @book.author = results.first["artistName"] 
      @book.bookname = results.first["trackName"] 
      @book.image = results.first["artworkUrl100"].gsub("100x100-75.jpg", "200x200-75.jpg") 
      @book.description = results.first["description"] 
    end
  end
```

I.e. a check to only create a new book and set its properties if a book was found. Now in the view, a check should be added to only render the rest of the view(the part that invokes `[]` operator on `@results` if results is not empty. This is achieved using an else statement:

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="span8 offset2">
   <% if @results.empty? %>
    <h1 class="resultTitle">sorry we can't find anything for that book.</h1>
     <%= link_to "Back To Search", root_path, :class => 'backButton' %>
   <% else %>  <--- I've putted an else instead of end here!!!


    <%= @results.first["trackName"] %> <br>
    <img src =<%= @results.first["artworkUrl100"] %>> <br>
    <%= @results.first["artistName"] %> <br>
    <%= truncate(remove_tags(@results.first["description"]), :length => 250) %> <br>

    <%= form_for @book do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :category_id, "Category" %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Please select a Category') %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :author %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :bookname %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :image %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :description %>

     <%= f.submit 'Save book' %>
    <% end %>
  <%end %> <--- Added an end for the if-else here.
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

So I have added an else and an end that I have indicated in the code. Why do you need to do that? Well because even after performing the check and displaying the message, the rest of the page was still evaluated and this bit: `%= @results.first["trackName"] %> <br>` was causing the error. You should not try to call the `[]` operator if you know `@results` is empty. The new version only displays the remaining part of the page in the else case i.e. if `@results` is not empty.

Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: where  could that error be? vague question i know, but any ideas?

Comment: ah i see because of the ? after nil

Comment: i have added my controller, is there anything you can see out of place

Comment: The correct version is with the questionmark. Please give all of the view code so that I can understand what's happening. The problem is in the view not the controller

Comment: @Richlewis I think I have found and fixed your problem. Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: I am sorry - forgot the question mark after `nil` as I copy-pasted the code from you. I have fixed that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22635/discussion-between-izomorphius-and-richlewis)